# Overloaded methods taking optional and no arguments: why no ambiguity?

Tags: c++, overloading

I'm surprised the following code compiled without any complaints in VS2005, because the call to Bar() in the implementation made me pause and wonder as to how to disambiguate.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(int param = 0);

private:
  void Bar();
};
```

where:

```
void Foo::Bar(int param)
{
  // do something
  return Bar();
}
```

Can anyone enlighten me?

EDIT:

D'oh!
Realised a gap in my understanding immediately...

My actual header was

```
class Foo : public IFoo
{
public:
  void Bar(int param);

private:
  void Bar();
};

class IFoo
{
public:
  virtual void Bar(int param = 0) = 0;
};
```

which is not the same as what I posted originally. I assumed it was.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=83043c816cfceac6b6a9ab530f8e34ba-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419).

Comment: And it's possible to disambiguate manualy: `(this->*static_cast<void(Foo::*)()>(&Foo::Bar))();`

Comment: @jrok about your second comment - how would that disambiguate anything? You're still using an ambiguous `Foo::Bar`...

Comment: @cluracan `static_cast` to the appropriate member function pointer does it.

Comment: @jrok: Yeah, my mistake... Too bad I can't downvote myself =/

Answer (score 0):

For a start as you have a method signature of 'void Foo::Bar(int paaram)`you do not need the`return`.

Also with default arguments you can with call it with or withour argumants.

Therefore calling `bar()` the compiler can either call (1) or (2) as they are all equally valid. So what is the compiler to do? All it can do is issue an error.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void Bar(int param = 0); (1)

private:
  void Bar(); (2)
};


void Foo::Bar(int param) (3)
{
  // do something
  Bar();
}
```

Comment: Apparently not *all* it can do.  VS 2005 (allegedly) managed to compile it.  The question is, why/how did it allow this?

Comment: @cHao Because it's broken :)

Comment: @cHao: My mistake, just realised soon after posting.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an ambiguous function an error prevents compilation. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void f(int, int = 2)
{
    cout<< "first f" << endl;
}
void f(int)
{
    cout<< "second f" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    f(2); // removing this live will let the error go    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disambiguate, either rename `Bar()` or move it to a base class like that:

```
class Base
{
protected:
    void Bar() { }
};

class Foo : public Base
{
public:
    void Bar(int param = 0)
    {
        // do something
        return Base::Bar();
    }
};
```